# Laplace smoothing in R

Tags: r, smoothing

I've been trying for a while to use Laplace smoothing in different columns but honestly, I haven't come to any working method, and theres not much content about this subject on the internet.

I'm currently working on a database with 43 variables and over 27k observations. the DF (time_data) looks like this:

```
time_data
       T01  T02  T03  T_TOT
 1     1    4    3      8
 2     5    2    0      7
 3     3    1    10     14

T_TOT = T01 + T02 + T03
```

As the name implies, each value correspond to an amount of seconds. For the sake of the example, let's say the max value T_TOT can be is 15 (seconds).

Because of the values are presented as discrete data, I was planning on decomposing the Laplace Smoothing into differente columns and calculate the new values at the end. The problem is that, in reality, I have 42 variables, and to do this i would end up with way to many variables.

is there any way in r to calculate the Laplace Smoothing?
if not, how could I create a loop to generate the new column with the Laplace values?

Expected Outcome:

```
       T01  T02  T03  T_TOT  L_T01  L_T02  Lt03
 1     1    4    3      8    ...    ...    ...
 2     5    2    0      7    ...    ...    ... 
 3     3    1    10     14   ...    ...    ...
```

brief explanation of Laplace smoothing: https://programmerclick.com/article/9417297724/

Comment: can you give us a reference or a link that explains what Laplace smoothing is?

Comment: https://programmerclick.com/article/9417297724/